# AngularJs directive one way data binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use one way data binding from controller to my directive, but I get `undefined` instead of real value.

Here is definition of directive `scope`

```
scope: {
    eventAdmin: '@',
    eventId: '@'
  }
```

Here is how I use directive.

```
<directive event-admin="{{eventAdmin}}" event-id="{{eventId}}"></directive>
```

And here is my `link` function

```
function directiveLink (scope, element, attrs) {
console.log(scope.eventId); //-> undefined
```

}

Comment: <directive event-admin="eventAdmin" event-id="eventId"></directive>

Comment: please post the complete directive code

Comment: trying consoling variable before the directive and see what that returns

Comment: Your code should work. Do you have an example of it not working?

Comment: @SamiTriki The OP is not asking for that. The OP is correctly binding to the value of the elements attribute. It's just that the value in initialized by the "parent" scope variable. This is what makes it "one way" binding.

Comment: Misunderstood the question, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directive's name is "directive" and the containing controller's scope has the properties "eventAdmin" and "eventId" then this should be working.

I made a JSFiddle of your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Royar/qu55ujj5/4/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <directive event-admin="{{eventAdmin}}" event-id="{{eventId}}"></directive>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.eventAdmin = "aaa";
  $scope.eventId = "bbb";

});
angular.module("myApp").directive("directive", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      eventAdmin: "@",
      eventId: "@"
    },
    template: "{{eventAdmin}}",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.eventAdmin); //working
    }
  };
});
```